# compress images before uploading using jquery file upload

Tags: jquery, jquery-file-upload

Am using the [jquery file upload plugin](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload) for direct upload to s3, I am trying to get the image compressed before upload it, I have tried the option `imageQuality: 0.8`

```
fileInput.fileupload({

            fileInput:       fileInput,
            url:             my_url
            type:            'POST',
            paramName:        'file',
            dataType:         'XML',
            replaceFileInput: false,
            acceptFileTypes: /(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png)$/i
            maxFileSize: 999000,  
            imageQuality: 0.8,

            // .....

})
```

However the image size doesn't get compressed after upload

Am not sure that `imageQuality` is the right thing here, but am open to any other alternative as well :

**For instance:** I have also created my own function to compress images, that function return the image Blob, I just have no idea how to tell **JQuery File Upload** to use that blob instead of the image from the input file

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I am going to answer my question after I found the solution hopefully this help someone in the future :

To compress an image using jquery file upload there is 2 solutions, either you use the compression provided by the plugin or you create your own compress function and use it with jquery file upload, I ended up using the second solution

**First solution:**

The thing I stumbled upon was this link: https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Client-side-Image-Resizing

So what you need to do basically is import the following files on your project: `jquery.js, jquery.ui.widget.js, load-image.all.min.js, canvas-to-blob.min.js, jquery.iframe-transport.js, jquery.fileupload.js, jquery.fileupload-process.js, jquery.fileupload-image.js`

Then looking at the options of jQuery File upload, I found the option [imageQuality](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Options#imagequality), reading it, it says :

> **imageQuality**: Sets the quality parameter given to the canvas.toBlob() call when
>   saving resized images.

So it seems that the **imageQuality** option works only when the image get resized, but in my case I don't need to resize the image, but you can use another option [imageForceResize](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Options#imageforceresize), by combining these 2 options you can make the compression work, but there is a third option needed **disableImageResize**, this option is set to true by default, so we need to set it to false to allow image resizing.

**The final code looks like this :**

```
$('#file_input').fileupload({

    # these 3 options are necessary together for compressing
    disableImageResize: false,
    imageForceResize: true,
    imageQuality: 0.7,
    // ......
})
```

**For the second solution :**

if you want to use your own compress function which in my opinion I think it's the best way to go, then in this case you just need `jquery.js, jquery.ui.widget.js, jquery.fileupload.js`

Jquery file upload store the files to upload in `data.files` before submit them, so what you have to do is to have a function that compress the image(s) and return an array of blobs, then overwrite `data.files`

```
$('#file_input').fileupload({

   add: function(e, data){
       // .......
       data.files = compress_images_function()
       data.submit()
   }

})
```

Comment: i dont know what i did wrong but when i apply this file upload, when i click choose file and select a file. it does nothing and still no file chosen. i set this #file_input things on form. which part should i check on. Thanks

Comment: @KevinFarel it's self explanatory, by #file_input I meant `<input type="file" id="file_input">`, try to apply fileupload to your input button instead of the form

Comment: The [blueimp file upload documentation](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Options#imagequality) says that the quality level is passed on to canvas.toBlob. [That documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toBlob) in turn says that the quality setting is not supported by Safari and Chrome for Android (and IE 11), and [caniuse agrees](https://caniuse.com/mdn-api_htmlcanvaselement_toblob_image_quality), which is a bummer. I wonder if there is any other way to change it. It seems kind of low.

Comment: @cesoid if I do remember I was using some kind of client side (js) solution to compress my images, but I do not remember if that solution was using canvas.toBlob too or not, you can search for a solution on github and use the second way like I described, another cool solution is to use https://imgproxy.net/ which you can install in your server, they have an open source version, there are other similar solution on the web as well